# Don't receive Paypal transaction details upon successful submission

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

I've Paypal sandbox account to test transaction.
I have passed all the required params as follows-

```
$paypalConfig = [
    'email' => 'sb-kn7oc852981@business.example.com',
    'return_url' => $site_url.'/dashboard/payments/paypal/payment-successful.php',
    'cancel_url' => $site_url.'/dashboard/payments/paypal/payment-cancelled.html',
    'notify_url' => $site_url.'/dashboard/payments/paypal/payments.php'
];
```

It did return transaction id initially for a couple of times but, stopped later on.

I have also enabled IPN on paypal, but it didn't work either.

Comment: SandBox sometimes have problems, try a real payment

Comment: @Xbattlax Have you experienced that before?

Comment: Yes, I have stopped to try PayPal sandbox, I only try with real paiement from my account to an other account

Comment: @Xbattlax Alright, let me test it out and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Xbattlax Thanks a lot friend. It really is working for live account, getting response in the GET method.

Comment: Although it will be great to see if there's someway to make it work for Sandbox too.

Comment: you're welcome !